# how to pass element in inline onclick event in a dynamically created string

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, onclick

I got a function that creates a button template for Kendo Grid Toolbar based on the parameter received. What I want to do is passing one of the properties inside the parameter called `element`(it is a jquery element) through onclick function so that I can access that element in the function `fnAdd(element)`.

```
 function(parameter)
 {
     var template="<button onclick='fnAdd("+param.element+")'>Add</button>";
     $('#grid').kendoGrid({
         toolbar: template
     });
 }
```

Currently, the onclick function is not working. I try to use JSON.stringify on the param and pass it through the onclick and able to get it on fnAdd(), but I can't access the param.element at all.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bind` method to attach your `params` to achieve this. Sample code below

```js
function add(param) {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'NEW - ' + new Date().getTime();
  btn.onclick = newButtonOnclick.bind(this, (param || new Date().getTime()))
  document.body.append(btn)
}

function newButtonOnclick(param) {
  alert(param);
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="add();">
Add New Button
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution can help you:

Remember the `Patter designs`, in this case we can use a `Factory patter` with this you can reuse this code to create chunks of code.

With this example also each button could trigger a different function and can have different params!

```
// YOUR JAVASCRIPT WITH ACCESS TO THE DOM
// here you call your plugin where the DOM is not present
function getButton() {
  let newButtonInString = createButtonPlugin();
  // in newButton you just have the string
  // now convert it to html using Jquery 
  let htmlButton = $(newButtonInString);
  document.body.append(htmlButton[0]);
}

// YOUR PLUGIN JS
let counter = 1;
function createButtonPlugin() {
  // you can take this params from the UI
   let paramsExample = {
     text: `New Button ${counter}`,
     functionParams: { 
       counter: counter
     }  // Could be an object or what you want!
   }

   let bp = new ButtonPrototype(paramsExample);
   let newButton = bp.createButton();
   counter++;
   // return string to the place where you can render the button
   return newButton;
}

class ButtonPrototype {
  constructor(params){
     this.params = params
  }

  createButton() {
    return `<button onclick=fn(${JSON.stringify(this.params.functionParams)})>${this.params.text}</button>`
  }
}

function fn (args) {
  alert(`Success ${args.counter}`)
}
```

Your html:

```html
<button onclick="getButton()">add</button>
```

I also leave the codepen: Just Updated with the new comment you made!
https://codepen.io/ruben-saucedo/pen/GbxXNG

Comment: i tried this.. and its not work.. I think is because the template that I generated is for the used of another plugin, so "it" doesnt know where to append it.. but thanks for your help

Comment: mmm, yeah make sense. But could you at least reference an element in the DOM within your plugin?
If yes, adding an id to the body of the DOM where you want to render the buttons could solve the issue.
Or is your plugin completely isolated for the DOM?
In that case instead of creating an html, just return a string. 
And render it on the place you want.
I have updated the codepen and comment if you want to check it!